# Extract the last published post

Tags: posts, export

How do I extract the last published post?

I would be grateful if someone can just point out the relevant action hooks that I should check out. I have seen publish_post, edit_post, save_post, get_the_tags, sanitize_** functions in `post.php` but so far no success.

I want to export the entire array of the last published post from the database. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You! I sorted this out myself thanks...

For any one who stumbles upon this, here's the resolution...

```
// Get the last n number of posts.

$args = array( 'numberposts' => 'n' ); // replace n with the number of posts
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.$recent["post_title"].'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
    echo '<li>Tags '.print_r($recent).'</li> ';
}
```

Comment: How can I use your code to check all the last posts of all custom post types including the native post type post?

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do it. You may want to reset and call it as a function in case you want to reuse.

// Most Recent

```
function nt_mostrecent( $count ) {

        $my_query = new WP_Query( array(showposts => $count, order => 'DSC', orderby => 'date'));

        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();

            $posts .= '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a>';

        endwhile;

        return $posts;

        wp_reset_query();

}
```

Comment: this is a more to-the-point approach...

wordpress also has a wp_get_recent_posts($args) function...

you can supply it 
     $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1' );

Comment: thanks for your time anyway... :) I dont have enough reputation to give your answer a 1-up for useful.. 

I will do so as soon as I get 15 points... thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Using wp-cli:

`wp post list --order='DESC' --orderby='ID' --field='ID' | head -1`